# Identify these non-LEGO vintage building logs

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, clone-brands, vintage

I found these little brick logs. Mum said they were sticklebricks but they're definitely not! Does anyone know what they are?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

These look like

[image]

I found a few [ebay listings](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Vintage-NOS-Plastic-Puzzle-Toys-on-Wheels-Tommy-Gun-Field-Gun-Made-in-Hong-Kong/174057395816) for this item, they seem to be from the 60's, but no luck on finding further information.